# how to create OAuth token with public/private key

Tags: java, oauth, key, public

I'm fairly new to OAuth but have done some PKI in the past.  Can anyone point me to some example on how to generate a OAuth token, application secret using public/private key? google didn't turn up any good results.

I've read the google oauth examples and the OAuth intro http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/history , but they're not really relevant. thx

Comment: Read http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ chapter 6, then 7 after you got the basics of the terminology in chapter 3. Then find a good OAuth library in Java.

Comment: OAuth tokens and secrets are not created in some special format - they are just strings and it's up to you how to generate these strings. There is no rule or definition in the specification as of what characters should be used to build the strings or what length are the strings supposed to be...for example valid token/secret are: aaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbb

Comment: got some clarification on the requirements today.  Our provider is not doing the whole 9 yards of OAuth (consumer being redirected to the login page, then send generate request token, etc.)  Since this is a company portal, consumers/provider are trusted, the provider I'm creating just needs to generate a time-sensitive token based on some value and append it to the querystring so the consumer can decrypt it.  what is the best way to accomplish this ?  thx

Comment: Trying to understand oauth.  How does pki fit into the scheme?  I found this good article:http://marktrapp.com/blog/2009/09/17/oauth-dummies/ but are those handshakes for getting the unauthorized tokens, for authorizing the token and for getting the access token, where pki comes in?